# PHP defining functions in classes

Tags: oop, php

Very simple question here. Doing my first OO programming in PHP, more used to Java & C#.

With this class definition:

```
class RouteParser {
    var $DEBUG = 1;

    function parse($from, $to, $route){
        debug("test");
        debug("test again");
    }

    function debug($arg) {
        if($DEBUG) {
            echo "<pre>DEBUG: " . print_r($arg) . "</pre>";
        }
    }
}
```

And this executing code:

```
include("RouteParser.php");
$rp = new RouteParser();
$return = $rp->parse("from","to","test");
```

I'm getting the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function debug() in
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\routeparse\RouteParser.php
>   on line 7

PHP doesn't support function prototypes as far as I can tell, so I'm stumped on how to tell one class function that another class function exists... according to what I found on the PHP documentation, this is only an issue if the function is inside a conditional (which makes sense)...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `$this->debug()` instead. `$this` makes PHP look for the function in the class itself, while just `debug()` makes PHP look for a function called debug in the global scope.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Well, it doesn't, compared to other languages, but I understand what you are saying... ;-)

Comment: If the method is static, you would refer to it inside the class itself with `self::debug()`.